# Why gunicorn cannot find static files?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

Running Django dev server has no problem: 'python manage.py runserver 9000'
But if use gunicorn, it complains:

'http://innovindex.com/pubmed/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js '

Why gunicorn cannot find a local jquery but Django can?

The settings are:

settings.py (seems not related):

```
STATIC_URL = '/pubmed/static/'
```

in '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django'

```
location /static {
   alias /home/django/innovindex/pubmed/static/;
}
```

And my app looks like this:

/home/django/innovindex

is where the 'manage.py' sits.

THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: As @The_Cthulhu_Kid mentioned you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` to generate your static files into a single directory for things to work. If you do a `ls -al /home/django/innovindex/pubmed/static/` you will find it to be empty as of now

Comment: Why would gunicorn have any business with static files? gunicorn is a WSGI server, it does not deal with static files.

Comment: Your static files are served by Nginx not Gunicorn. Check your nginx config, even better serving static files with nginx

Comment: should be alias /home/django/innovindex/pubmed instead of /home/django/innovindex/pubmed/static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/) in the Django documentation, you must run the `collectstatic` command in addition to setting the `STATIC_ROOT` setting.

First make sure that you're STATIC_ROOT is set to the correct path that matches your nginx config:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/innovindex/pubmed/static/'
```

Note that this is an absolute path.

Then run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

in your project directory.

This will copy all of your static files into `/home/django/innovindex/pubmed/static/`

Comment: It might be helpful if the django documentation here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) mentioned this issue and linked to the static files documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out until I found that the below must be in your main `urls.py`. Just add those two lines.

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... 

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Note that staticfiles_urlpatterns() will only work when DEBUG = True is set in your settings.py. This is not a proper solution for production environment.  more info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns

Comment: Wei Jing. This is not a correct datum. My site runs with the above solution and with DEBUG = False.